# On which networks does the Gnosis Safe UI deploy the singleton vs the sidechain singleton thru the proxy factory?

Tags: gnosis-safe, gnosis

This does not seem to be documented anywhere or exist in the safe-react repo or the safe-client-gateway repo code but affects if safe proxies that are deployed outside the safe-react app can be monitored through the safe-transaction-service API. Since both versions of both singletons are deployed to each and every chain but one does not allow tracking through the safe-transaction-service API it is very confusing. Where does this logic actually exist?

Answer (score 1):

Mainnet and rinkeby deploy the general singleton, all other chains use the sidechain singleton